# How can i merge an array to get a structure

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array such that

```
[[{"qId":1.3,"id":1}],[{"qId":1.3,"id":2},{"qId":1.3,"id":3}, {"qId":1.4,"id":3}]]
```

How can i merge them such that it becomes :

```
[{"qId":1.3,"id":[1,2,3]},{"qId":1.4,"id":[3]}]
```

I have tried to use _.uniq but does not work the way it gives me the structure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try something ? I think no method can do that, you have to make it yourself

Comment: Very good concept... But im not sure if thats possible yet.

Comment: Asked and answered many times. Search for "group array of objects by property" or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

You can concat the array and then iterate over the array and collect the data with a temporary object and the result array.

```js
var array = [[{ "qId": 1.3, "id": 1 }], [{ "qId": 1.3, "id": 2 }, { "qId": 1.3, "id": 3 }, { "qId": 1.4, "id": 3 }]],
    merged = function (array) {
        var o = {}, r = [];
        [].concat.apply([], array).forEach(function (a) {
            if (!(a.qId in o)) {
                o[a.qId] = { qId: a.qId, id: [] };
                r.push(o[a.qId]);
            }
            o[a.qId].id.push(a.id);
        });
        return r;
    }(array);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(merged, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
var array = [
  [{
    "qId": 1.3,
    "id": 1
  }],
  [{
    "qId": 1.3,
    "id": 2
  }, {
    "qId": 1.3,
    "id": 3
  }, {
    "qId": 1.4,
    "id": 3
  }]
]
//flatten the array inside array into a single array
var flatten = [].concat.apply([], array);
var final = [];

flatten.forEach(function(a1) {
    //check in the final list with the quid
    var filtered = final.filter(function(f) {
      return f.qId == a1.qId
    });
    if (filtered.length == 0) {
      //if not present make an object with  id
      var grp = {
        id: []
      };
      grp.qId = a1.qId;
      final.push(grp);
    } else {
      //get  first element of filtered
      grp = filtered[0]
    }
    grp.id.push(a1.id);
})
console.log(final)
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/kubzo2wy/)